# Why is my java -version showing " openjdk version "1.8.0_282" "

Tags: java

[image]

This is what my CMD looks like. I have JDK 11 but for some reason it shows my version is 1.8.  My netbeans uses JDK11. How do I update it from version 1.8?

EDIT: This is JAVA_HOME
[image]

and Path

[image]

Comment: And at this point, you'd want to change the order of the paths in your PATH env variable . Just make sure, the jdk-11 line is at top.

Comment: Remember to pick the answer, that solved your issue!

Answer (score 6):

Windows will run whatever Java is first in your `PATH`. Therefore, you might want to check your environment variables and also check `JAVA_HOME`, when you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Environment variables > JAVA_HOME > Edit > paste the path of your JDK 11  here instead of JDK-8 path > Go to *PATH* and now paste the path of the bin folder of JDK 11 here and press ok**

You can check the version of JDK now over CMD.

Explanation:

ClassPath decides where all commands will be present.Java code should be locatable & is located using classPath where you specify root directories of all projects that you want to run.

Comment: Ok, now it shows version 11, thanks!

Comment: you're welcome!